# Can't set datepicker date from controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to create an AngularJS datepicker on the push of a button. I am using [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) bootstrap-ui control. The control works (pops up on the click of a button, and I can select a date), but I can't seem to set the initial date back from the scope (so that when it is first opened, the designated date is already selected).

The error I get in the Chrome console is:

> Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.

jade:

```
button(type="button" ng-model="date.from" btn-radio="'From'" ng-click="date.openFromPopup($event);" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false" datepicker-popup = "date.format" is-open = "date.fromOpened" min = "date.minDate" max = "date.today") From
```

Since I have a watch on `$scope.date.from`, I can confirm that the selected date is correct, but I can never set it from the controller. Any ideas?

AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.date = {};

$scope.date.format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
$scope.date.opened = false;
$scope.date.from = new Date();
$scope.date.today = new Date();
$scope.date.minDate = null;
$scope.date.fromOpened = false;

$scope.$watch('date.from', function(v) {
if(v){
     alert(v);
}
});
```

Comment: Try changing `new Date()` to `new Date().toISOString()`. If that works, I'll add an answer.

Comment: the same when You enter the date by hand (editable input)

Answer (score 0):

In the example on the angular-ui page, it says to use it like this...

```
$scope.from = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
};
$scope.from();
```

Does that work?