# Invalid "ng-model" value with Bootstrap UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a simple datepicker directive in my AngularJS application. Following the [UI Bootstrap Documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) I get this error every time:

> Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number
>   of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822
>   or ISO 8601 date.

I have found a few other related issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980305/angular-bootstrap-ui-datepicker-with-custom-directive-parser-causes-error-not) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341806/cant-set-datepicker-date-from-controller-in-angularjs), but neither of them were helpful.

I tried accessing $parent and $parent.$parent like suggested [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/808), which will get rid of the error, but it doesn't update the model.

Here is a Plunker recreating the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CAUGqZnH77SbknmGTFiL?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
 </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppControl as appCtrl">
    <label>{{dt | date:'fullDate'}}</label>

    <input type="text" 
             class="form-control" 
             datepicker-popup="MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a" 
             ng-model="dt" 
             is-open="opened"
             datepicker-options="dateOptions"
             ng-required="true" 
             close-text="Close" />

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">Pick</button>
    </span>

    <script>
      angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).controller("AppControl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.opened = false;
        $scope.dateOptions = {};
        $scope.dt = new Date();
        $scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $scope.opened = true;
        };
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the format you are providing in the attribute 'datepicker-popup'.

Use the value of the attribute as 'longDate' as follows :

```
datepicker-popup="longDate"
```

Use it as follows :

```
<input type="text" 
             class="form-control" 
             datepicker-popup="fullDate" 
             ng-model="dt" 
             is-open="opened"
             datepicker-options="dateOptions"
             ng-required="true" 
             close-text="Close" />
```

I updated the plnkr.

Comment: Thank you! So is there no way to add a custom date format? Or was there a problem with the one I used. I've used it in the past without issues.

Comment: You can use any format which returns a Date object and apparently the format which you used was not returning the Date object. For more date formats please have a look at : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @VaibhavPachauri documentation says filter returns string in the new format. Is this a reason datepicker-pop will throw the error?

Comment: @alphapilgrim Most probably the problem is with the ui-datepicker directive not being able to parse the format "MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a" . Probably the literal 'at' wasn't being parsed properly. I am not sure about this though. Will have to test that out :)